# Make program startup through windows service c#

Tags: c#, windows, service, startup

I have a program starting up through the registry, but I want it to start up more efficiently. So I asked some questions and I have found out that a windows service is the way forward. I have looked at how to make a windows service but I have not found any answers for what I need.

I am trying to create a checkbox on my application so that when it is checked it adds a service to start up my application when the person logs in, and when it is not checked it deletes the service.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the correct way.  Services cannot find out when a user logs in since Vista.  In your prior thread you got the advice to create *two* programs, although that wasn't explicitly stated.  A service that runs after the machine boots and a user interface that allows the user to communicate with the service after she logs in.

You'll need an inter-process communication mechanism to get them to talk to each other.  Named pipes, a socket, Remoting or WCF will work.

Read the MSDN Library docs on the ServiceBase class, that's what you'll need to create a service.